Are post permalinks and wp_redirect() redirections saved in browser cache?
Permanent 301 redirections are stored in client browser cache. Theoretically this means they cannot be modified after they has been set, because browser will just follow the initial, cached redirection, and won't even make a new request and ask a server if there has been redirection updates.
However, although they are 301 permanent, posts permalinks can be modified, and seems like browser is not saving them in cache.
Is this because of the Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store header, which I see in Dev Tools -> Network tab?
My main questions are:

Are post permalinks cached/not cached by default?
Is wp_redirect() cached/not cached by default?
I am actually using vip_substr_redirect. Is it cached by default?
If I change the post permalink or update the wp_redirect or vip_substr_redirect settings, can I be sure that clients will be properly redirected?
If I delete a post with custom permalink, and use that exact same permalink in another, new post, can I be sure clients won't get 401?


wp_redirect default code is 302 Moved Temporarily : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/
